# Show first image and display none other image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I have one question about displaying image. I have created this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/pvVBme)** from *codepen.io*

In this demo you can see there is a two `.image_container` div. And this divs inside have tree image. First div showing tree image and second div showing only one image (other 2 image `display:none;`). I want to make it like second `.image_container` (Show first image and `display:none;` other two or more image.) How can i do that width jquery or CSS anyone can help me here ?

I tryed like this javascript but it is display:none; other `.image_container` div inside image.

javascript

```
$(".image_container a:first-child").css("display", "block");
```

HTML

```
 <div class="container">
      <div class="image_container">
        <a href="#"><img src="http://fantasy-faction.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Avatar.jpg"</a>
          <a href="#"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/38/Avatarjakeneytiri.jpg"</a>
            <a href="#"><img src="http://fc09.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2010/015/8/9/Cristiano_Ronaldo_avatar_by_Tsunamy_boy.png"</a>
      </div>
      <div class="image_container">
         <a href="#"><img src="http://fantasy-faction.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Avatar.jpg"</a>

          <a href="#" class="none"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/38/Avatarjakeneytiri.jpg"</a>
            <a href="#" class="none"><img src="http://fc09.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2010/015/8/9/Cristiano_Ronaldo_avatar_by_Tsunamy_boy.png"</a>
            <div clas="need">Want to make like this</div>  
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
    body {
      background-color:#000;
    } 
    .container {
      margin:0px auto;
      width:650px;
      height:auto;
      margin-top:50px;
    }
    .image_container {
      float:left;
      width:300px;
      background-color:#ffffff;
      border-radius:3px;
      padding-bottom:30px;
      margin-right:20px;
    }
    .image_container  img {
      width:300px;
      height:auto;
    }
    .none {
      display:none;
    }
    .need {
      float:left;
      width:300px;
      background-color:red;
    }
.image_container a{display:none;}
```

Comment: I'm confused with your question. What is your end goal?

Comment: @dowomenfart I want to make it like second image like in [DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/pvVBme) page.

Comment: @dowomenfart show first image and display:none other 2 image.

Comment: Like this? http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/pvVBme?editors=110

Comment: you can try this once 
`.image_container a{display:none;}` and `.image_container a:first-child{display:block;}`

Comment: @dowomenfart I try this but you can see. If i use `.image_container a:nth-child(n+2){display:none;}` and if .image_container div has 1 image then that image automatically `display:none;`

Comment: @NiketThapa but if the `.image_container` has one image then ???? I think i need jquery for it. Because if i use only CSS then automatically displayed (none) other `.image_container` inside image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your test is almost right.

Your problem is not CSS or JavaScript but HTML it self, them are `img` tags are not properly formed. They are `<img src="path_to_image"` but should be `img` tags are not properly formed. They are `<img src="path_to_image">` (notice the closing `>`).

Since your HTML is bad formed I will not assume the rules needed to selected the elements the browser defines.

But Fixing the HTML gives a result that looks with what you want.

Comment: So how many pictures `display:none;` Can I do it was with JavaScript ? Like in this post have other 2 image click to see.. ext.

Comment: Any number... Are you trying to create some thing like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_carousel.asp)?